# Would this be considered dependency injection in php/codeigniter?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, design-patterns

Would this be considered dependency injection?

```
<?php
class BASE_Model extends CI_Model 
{  
    /**
     * inject_class - load class using dependency injection
     *
     * @access public
     * @param  string $path
     * @param  string $class
     * @param  string $func
     * @param  string $method
     **/
    public function inject_class($path, $class, $func, $method)
    {
        // load_class is a function located in system/core/common.php on line 123
        $obj = load_class($class, $path, NULL);
        return $obj->$func();
    }
}

// lets say this is instantiated by a user controller when a new user is made
class User_model extends BASE_Model
{
    public function create()
    {
        echo 'create a new user';
        $request = $this->inject_class('path/to/models', 'Logger_model', 'log');
        echo $request;
    }
}

class Logger_model extends BASE_Model
{
    public function log()
    {
        return 'Logged';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. That's just another way of how the object loads dependencies itself. The point of dependency injection is that every method/object/function takes its dependencies as arguments and does *not* load them itself in any way. `User_model::create` is <strike>injecting</strike> loading another class by itself, which is not *accepting the dependency as an argument*.

The point of dependency injection is to reduce coupling. The `User_model` is now coupled to the `Logger_model` class, since it hardcodes the name and path to that specific class inside itself. If you wanted to use or test the `User_model` by itself in isolation, without it logging stuff you don't want, you cannot do so anymore. Real DI would be this:

```
public function create(Logger_model $log) {
    // here be dragons
    $log->log();
}
```

This way you can inject a mocked dummy logging class when you want to test the method without breaking anything or use alternative types of loggers when needed without needing to change any code.

Comment: so then I would pass the instance of that Looger_model via my User controller to the User_model?

Comment: Exactly. But, true DI is very hard in frameworks like Codeigniter, Cake and similar ones, since they're very firmly ***not*** build on DI principles. So even if you can achieve *some* DI, it's an uphill battle and questionable whether it's worth it.

Comment: True, I've been doing a lot of require_once with $x = new X_model(); or $this->load->model('x_model');  I figured somehow implementing DI would make my structure loosely coupled. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I have read almost source code related to dependency loading but don't how they accomplish that. Different models are able to communicate with each other